# create java class in FeatureIDE with Munge Composer

Tags: java, eclipse, software-product-lines, munge

I tried the example project (*HelloWorld*) on FeatureIDE with Munge and it worked properly. I easily created class is the '*source*' folder and they are automaticaly created in the '*src*' folder after preprocessing .

But I don't know how to create a class in my own FeatureIDE project when Munge is selected as a composant. I tried to create the '*source*' folder and files into it but it doesn't work.

I do not find tutorial or documentation about it on the web.

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: This question does not show research effort. If you are having problems please post your current best guess. You should review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you should not modify "src" folder in FeatureIDE. Probably you should look at "features" folder.